# PowerShell to read log files on bunch of windows servers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read a log file on bunch of windows servers using PowerShell.

```
$servers = Get-Content -path D:\temp\input.txt
$logfile = "D:\temp\outlog.log"

ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
write-host "Server Name is: $server" | Out-FIle -filepath $logfile 
get-content "\\$server\c$\Windows\Logs\SCCM Schedule Defrag Task [VER 02.01 x86].log"
}
```

I get error

> Get-Content : An object at the specified path \TEST-PC\c$\Windows\Logs\SCCM Schedule Defrag Task [VER 02.01 x86].log does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.

I would like to know where and how i need to put quotes so as `get-content` command runs successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need two backslashes before $server